# ssh.localhost.run tunnel configuration command on Shell

Tags: ssh, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am currently writing a shell script for automating.
Manually, I will create a new session `ssh.localhost.run` by input Tunnel information on PuTTY like this

[image: screenshot]

Full steps:

1. host name "ssh.localhost.run"
2. go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels
3. Source port 80, Destination is my IP's gate
4. check on "Remote"

Is there a command that allows me to configure tunnels with source ports like the steps ?

Comment: You cant expect to click on links to read things.  Why not put the essential steps here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta the page doesn't allow me to embed a picture in, it forces me to put in a link, I will edit specifically

Comment: Thats because of your reputation.  However, I have made it inline.

Comment: It's not strictly speaking a "command" but a command-line SSH client. Here's Microsoft instructions [how to run ssh in terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/ssh). If that doesn't cover this, further instructions are easy to find by searching `ssh tunneling` or `ssh port forwarding`.